# IE 9 rendering BUT not showing HTML generated by MVC 3. Other browsers do

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox, internet-explorer-9

I am very puzzled with this one. I thought it was going to be a five minutes problem, became a three days one.

This is the deal.

I have an MVC 3 application. It renders perfect in all browsers but IE 9 simply doesn't show anything.

Now, check this out. Very important.

When i open the "browser's debuggers" for Firefox (Firebug 1.11.1) and IE9 (F12), i found something weird.

Check my attachments...

When i right click on both browsers and ask for View Source, i can see the whole expected HTML there, but in the "debuggers", IE9 shows the body empty (I guess what's actually showing is the final result from rendering?).

Very Important, check in the View Source screenshot, this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 8 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title>LogOn</title>
.....

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/standard.js"></script>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/standard.ie.js"></script><![end if]-->
....

</head>
```

I don't even know what to ask specifically here. Are these [if lte...] statements work in every browser? I don't have a clue what's going on here guys.

Anyone that has walked thru the valley of death before???

Thanks

EDIT:

I am using a template that i purchased on themeforest.net. Their sample (pure HTML) works perfectly fine in all browsers. They also look the same to my code (the header part of course) when i click on ViewSource. That's why i am assuming there is something to do with how i am rendering from MVC.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's impossible to read those images. Post the code at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or something.

Comment: First thing I would do is to run the rendered markup through a [validator](http://validator.nu)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question....

It had to do with this line

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/standard.ie.js")"></script><![endif]-->
```

It was rendered incorrectly. Now it's all good.